# Time complexity of this recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, time-complexity

I was trying to figure out runtime complexity of this recurrence using master theorem. I am kinda lost on this so according to master theorem .

> T(n)=aT(n/b))+f(n)

I plug in the value

> How many recursion (split) functions are there?

a = 1

> Relative subproblem size. What rate is the input reduced?

b = L as the subproblem is independent list

> Runtime of the work done outside the recursion?

f(n) = n for example there might be no list just integer

> Which case of master theorem would apply to this?

```
/*
341. Flatten Nested List Iterator on leetcode
 Given a nested list of integers, implement an iterator to flatten it.

Each element is either an integer, or a list -- whose elements may also be integers or other 
lists.

Input: [[1,1],2,[1,1]]
Output: [1,1,2,1,1]
Explanation: By calling next repeatedly until hasNext returns false, 
          the order of elements returned by next should be: [1,1,2,1,1].
*/

void recurse(vector<NestedInteger>& nestedList){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nestedList.size(); i++){
        if(nestedList[i].isInteger()){
            res.push_back(nestedList[i].getInteger());
        }else{
            recurse(nestedList[i].getList());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you have `T(n) = T(n/x)`, it means that this will run `logₓ(n)` times.

Answer (score 0):

This particular recursive problem is not well-modeled using the Master Theorem. The Master Theorem is good for recurrence relations where the size of the input shrinks by some constant factor on each recursive call. In your case, that's not necessarily true. For example, consider flattening this list:

```
[[[[[[[[...[[[1]]]...]]]]]]]]]
```

Here, each recursive call only decreases the size of the list by one, rather than being divided by some constant. As a result, you can't apply the Master Theorem here.

I think you may have more luck analyzing this recursion if you reframe the way that you have your list represented. You can think of your list as being a binary tree, where a list is represented as a chain of nodes moving to the right, while a sublist is represented as a left subtree. So, for example, the input

```
[1, [2, 3], [[4]]
```

would look like this:

```
 1
  \
   *
  / \
 2   \
  \   \
   3   *
      /
     *
    /
   4
```

Your recursive algorithm does O(1) work whenever visiting a node, plus the work required to process the right subtree (the rest of the list) and the left subtree (a recursive list, assuming that the item is a list). In that sense, you visit each node in the binary tree once, doing O(1) work per node, for a net total of O(n) work.